# How to create parametrized selector in NGXS?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs

I would like to create a selector with arguments. Is there a clean way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation, under selectors, you can find [memoized selectors with arguments](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/concepts/select#memoized-selectors-with-arguments):

```
@State<string[]>({
  name: 'animals',
  defaults: []
})
export class YourState{

  static selectorName(yourArgument: string) {
    return createSelector([YourState], (state: string[]) => {
      return state.filter(s => s === yourArgument);
    });
  }
}
```

You can then use your selector like this:

```
@Select(YourState.selectorName('yourArgument')) selectedStuf;
```

Next time, add some code examples from what you have already tried.